# how to return a global array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).on("click", "#subtotal", function() {       
    var total_price=0;                                        
    for (i=1; i<= clicks; i++) {
        var element = parseFloat($("#total_price_"+i).html());
        total_price += parseFloat(element);
        var brand_code = $("#brand_"+i).val();
        var price = $("#price_"+i).html();
        var quantity = $("#quantity_"+i).html();
        if (element >=1 ) {
        total_price 
        $("#total").html(total_price);
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "modules/query_jquery/product_select.php",
                   data: {"new_invoice": "new_invoice", "brand_code": brand_code, "price" : price, "quantity" : quantity , "total_price" : total_price},
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function (data) {
                      message = data.message;
                      window.location.href = data.url;
                    }
            });

        }

    }
    alert(message);
});
```

i am trying to alert message but it's not defined ??
variable message that defined under the ajax jquery can not be defined ? !!!

Comment: Its async, the alert will happen before the ajax call is done. That's the first gotcha. However, you havent defined `message` before the call so that's why you get the `undefined`

Comment: how to overcome such conflict ? !

Comment: You can either use `.complete();` or put the alert in the `success`-function.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the alert once the Ajax is complete:

```
  success: function (data) {
      message = data.message;
      window.location.href = data.url;
      test();
  }

  function test() {
      if (window.message) {
          alert(message);
      } else {
          alert("global message was not populated");
      }
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much .. worked .. i thought about it but i said to myself maybe i may find another solution without even creating a function.. thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

AJAX request are handeld asynchron!

When alert is called, the HTTP request hasn't returned yet.

Use

- the async flag (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- Deffer the call
- Call the method from your success method

Example for deffering the ajax request:

```
        $(function () {
            var req1 = $.get('test1.json').success(function (data) {
                $('body').append(data.hallo);
            });
            var req2 = $.get('test2.json').success(function (data) {
                $('body').append(data.welt);
            });

            $.when(req1, req2).done(function () {
                $('body').append('<br />ajax completed');
            }).fail(function () {
                $('body').append('<br />ajax failed');
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, because you're defining your global var inside a ajax success function it means that if this isn't successful this var won't exist for you to call on.

So define `message` before the ajax call to be on the safe side:

```
message = null;

$(document).on("click", "#subtotal", function() {       
var total_price=0;                                        
for (i=1; i<= clicks; i++) {
    var element = parseFloat($("#total_price_"+i).html());
    total_price += parseFloat(element);
    var brand_code = $("#brand_"+i).val();
    var price = $("#price_"+i).html();
    var quantity = $("#quantity_"+i).html();
    if (element >=1 ) {
    total_price 
    $("#total").html(total_price);
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "modules/query_jquery/product_select.php",
               data: {"new_invoice": "new_invoice", "brand_code": brand_code, "price" : price, "quantity" : quantity , "total_price" : total_price},
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (data) {
                  message = data.message;
                  window.location.href = data.url;
                }
        });

    }

}
alert(message);
});
```